# Must singular point behave bad analytically?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Here is an interesting [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety) from wikipedia: the equation $y^3+2x^2y-x^4=0$ defines a smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, despite that both partial derivatives vanish at $(0,0)$, i.e., $(0,0)$ is algebraically a singular point. The wiki article then says:

> the curve has two complex conjugate branches that cut the real branch at the origin.

I don't understand what that means, but I suppose it implies $y^3+2x^2y-x^4=0$ does not define a smooth real surface in $\mathbb{C}^2=\mathbb{R}^4$. I wonder if this is a general phenomenon, i.e., if $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial, $f(0,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, must the behavior of the solution set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2\mid f(x,y)=0\}$ be "bad" in analytic sense around $(0,0)$? For example could it still be a smooth real surface?

Comment: It's saying that if you draw out the solution set--including complex solutions--there are two branches that intersect at $(0, 0)$.  Imagine, for example, the solution set to $x^2 = y^2$.  This is a pair two lines that intersect at $(0, 0)$, so $(0, 0)$ is a singular point.

Also, $\mathbb C^2$ is not the same as $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @JosephCamacho I want to view the complex solutions as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, so I identify $\mathbb{C}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$, a variety is a smooth complex manifold if and only if it is nonsingular in the algebraic sense. See [this MathOverflow answer]{https://mathoverflow.net/a/98372/6751), which gives a reference to a proof.

Comment: @JackLee Thanks for pointing to that answer. Do you know any reference other than Milnor's book (I can't really make sense of it)? Is there an easy explanation for the case of a single polynomial $f(x,y)$?

Comment: No, I don't know of any other reference or any simpler proof. If you find one, let me know!